# SSH: No connection from specific IP

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables, fail2ban

On one of my VPS I'm facing a problem with SSH. I can't connect from home, but I can connect from other VPS. KiTTY gets **Connection timeout** and using the Windows command line `telnet [host] 22` gets **Connect failed**.

VPS uses fail2ban, but running `iptables -L fail2ban-SSH -v -n` is showing other blocked IP addresses but not mine.

Doing `iptables -L -v -n | grep "[my IP]"` isn't showing my IP address anywhere, so it's safe to conclude that I'm not being blocked by the firewall.

I have also checked `/etc/hosts.deny` but there is nothing there.

Doing a `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep [my IP]` there are only accepted connection messages from yesterday and before.

Doing a `cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep "[my IP]"` isn't showing anything.

Restarting the SSH daemon didn't help

Connecting to other VPSes from home, works fine.

I didn't restart the home router, because that would give me a different IP and most probably would work. But I need to figure out what is going on. I would restart fail2ban only as a last resort, for the same reason.

Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: Don't use fail2ban.

Comment: What alternatives do you propose?